# 3d histogram of coin flips results in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, 3d, histogram

My goal is to generate a 3d histogram of the probability of obtaining a certain number of heads in a first and second sequence of 4 coin flips each.

My idea is simple:

- use `expand.grid` to take the cartesian product of the probabilities  of a certain number of heads in the first and second sequence
- apply a product operation to each item in the cartesian product to obtain the probability of having that many heads in the first AND that many heads in the second. I think the trouble is in this step.
- show them in a 3d histogram.

But I get an extremely confusing output I cannot comprehend:

[image: Weird output]

I would expect and output with bars lower at the extremes (hard to get 0 head in the first AND in the second) and high in the middle (easier to get 2 heads in the first AND in the second).

```
require("plot3D")

x <- c(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/8
y <- c(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/8

prod <- function( arr ) { return (arr[1]*arr[1])}

z <- as.matrix(apply(expand.grid(x,y), c(1,2), prod))

print(z)
##  Plot as a 3D histogram:
hist3D(z=z, border="black")
```

Also the output of `expand.grid` looks too linear, instead of a table as a cartesian product should:

```
    Var1  Var2
1  0.125 0.125
2  0.375 0.125
3  0.375 0.125
4  0.125 0.125
5  0.125 0.375
6  0.375 0.375
7  0.375 0.375
8  0.125 0.375
9  0.125 0.375
10 0.375 0.375
11 0.375 0.375
12 0.125 0.375
13 0.125 0.125
14 0.375 0.125
15 0.375 0.125
16 0.125 0.125
```

Comment: @ Caridorc just realized that probability density function should add to 1 to be valid. your prob_x, prob_y should both be: `c(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/16` and similarly it will produce a sum for `z` equal to 1. Added some more details to code for clarity too.

Comment: @Mankind_008 thanks, I had done with one less coin before and forgot the *2 multiplier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given *x* and *y* are the number of heads in *1st and 2nd* sequence of coin flips respectively coming from *independent binomial distributions*.

You need to **evaluate `z` as a joint probability distribution over the grid of** `x` and `y`, where ***x, y € {0,1,2,3,4}***

```
require("plot3D")

x_val <- 0:4                    # No of heads in 1st sequence of flips
y_val <- 0:4                    # No of heads in 2nd sequence of flips

px <- c(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/16       # probability vector for no of flips 
py <- c(1, 4, 6, 4, 1)/16       # in 1st and 2nd sequence of flips

grid_prob <- mesh(px, py)
z  <- with(grid_prob, x*y)      # sum(z) should equal 1 to be a pdf

# Plot as a 3D histogram:
hist3D(z=z, border="black", x = x_val , y = y_val)
```

[image: joint pdf for x and y]